# How do I arrange an array in terms of another?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

Let's say I have two arrays

```
names[5]={a,b,c,d,e]; 

marks[5]={3,2,6,7,2};
```

Now I sort the marks array using an inbuilt function. How can I arrange the names array in the same order as the marks array?

Comment: @YuHao The language is C++.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried any. I don't know what to do. I want to be able to access the name and marks of a person with the same index(marks[1] are the marks of names[1]). @benrudgers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each name is apparently associated with a mark, you normally want to create a `struct` that contains one name and its associated mark.

```
struct foo { 
    char name;
    int mark;
};
```

Then we create an array of those:

```
foo marks[] = { { 'a', 3},
                { 'b', 2},
                { 'c', 6},
                { 'd', 7},
                { 'e', 2}
             };
```

Then we sort those items:

```
std::sort(std::begin(marks), std::end(marks),
          [](foo const &a, foo const &b) { return a.mark < b.mark; });
```

Note the last little bit that specifies how to do the sorting, based on the `mark` field of each `foo`.

From there we might (for example) want to print the marks out in order by the mark value:

```
for (auto const &f : marks)
    std::cout << f.name << "\t" << f.mark << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an array (vector would be better as shown below) of pairs by using std::pair from STL. Then sort the array of pairs. Here is an example ([try it live](http://ideone.com/VgwuFF)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    vector<pair<int,string>> v;

    v.push_back({10,"John"});
    v.push_back({5,"Katarina"});

    sort(v.begin(), v.end());

    for(int i=0;i<v.size();++i)
    {
        cout<<v.at(i).first<<" "<<v.at(i).second<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** this example uses C++11. To compile this code with g++ you need to use `-std=c++11` flag.

Comment: Thanks @mustafa. I'm a beginner, so could you post code as an example so I know to use it.